# Avoiding global variables by using persistent variables in MATLAB

Tags: globals, matlab

Disclaimer: Although I mention my use in matlab I think this is is more of a programming pattern question so I put it here. If I am incorrect I will be happy to go over to stackoverflow.

I have a variable comprising of strings array which acts like a database I need to refer to in several functions in my program. It gets initialized at the start of the program and then remains static. I need to search particular string in the variable an return the index. I don't want to use global variables because they are bad patterns usually. But in this case the next best thing I can come up with is to make a searchDB(string1) function which has a persistent variable to hold the string array. But this does not sound like a very good solution. What are some other ways to implement it?